# Application which runs on Ipad2 crashes without any exception

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

I made an application which runs on iPad. When i start the application on Simulator, I'm getting no error but if I want to run it on some iPad it crashes with no any error. And additionally the crashing happens only on iPad and randomly. I mean sometimes it crashes on second try, sometimes on the fifth or ninth. Why could this happen?

Comment: you need to run it on the ipad while its connected so that you can see the console output and the error.  More then then likely however it is because the emulator is NOT case sensitive and the device is.  So in some view you have an image that isnt referenced correctly.

Comment: Can you share stack trace ? I suspect it to be a memory crash. Are you getting memory warnings ? You can check in "iPhone Configuration Utility" app the device logs.

Comment: What are the Target Deployments on your Project Settings and on what IOS Device you are deploying

Comment: +1 for memory issue. Also, check your device log in XCode organizer for `low memory` warnings of 2nd level